# What are the key file formats of JSch and sharpSSH?

Tags: c#, java, sftp, jsch, sharpssh

I'm looking at setting up public key client and server authentication for SFTP using the JSch library (or actually the [sharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) C# port of it). Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation for the file formats used by the key loading functions:

```
jsch.addIdentity(filename, passphrase);
jsch.setKnownHosts(filename);
```

What file format is used by the private key and known hosts files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSch uses the OpenSSH **key file** format (both for public and private keys). I didn't find a specification of this format, but you can use OpenSSH's [ssh-keygen](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&sektion=1) tool to convert the keys from/to other formats (and Google will show other tools of converting from/to even more formats).

**Update:** After asking on the OpenSSH mailing list and reading some RFC's, it looks like OpenSSH's public key file contains (for version 2 keys) the public key as specified in [RFC 4253 (section 6.6)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-15), just with a base64-wrapping around it (and the key type as prefix, and a comment field as postfix). I still didn't yet find a specification for the private key file.

Unfortunately, the official documentation for JSch is almost nonexistent, but I did write some [Javadocs](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/) for it. (Though it seems not to mention the key file format ... I'll have to fix this.)
There is also the [Manual](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Manual) in the JSch Wiki, containing a page about [public key authentication](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Public_key_authentication) (which also doesn't mention the key format yet :-/).

The **known hosts file** is also in the same format as the corresponding file of the OpenSSH client. It's format is explained in [OpenSSH's sshd manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8), section *SSH KNOWN HOSTS FILE FORMAT*:

> Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers
> (optional), hostnames, bits, exponent, modulus, comment.  The fields are
> separated by spaces.

This is actually only correct for SSH 1 RSA keys. For SSH 2 keys, you have a type identifier (`ecdsa-sha2-nistp256`,`ecdsa-sha2-nistp384`, `ecdsa-sha2-nistp521`, `ssh-dss` or `ssh-rsa`) and then the key in base-64 encoded form. (See a bit up in the same manual page, for the authorized keys file). (I think JSch only supports the DSA and RSA key formats, no ECDSA.)

> Note that the lines in these files are typically hundreds of characters
> long, and you definitely don't want to type in the host keys by hand.
> Rather, generate them by a script, ssh-keyscan(1) or by taking
> /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub and adding the host names at the front.
> ssh-keygen(1) also offers some basic automated editing for
> ~/.ssh/known_hosts including removing hosts matching a host name and
> converting all host names to their hashed representations.

Comment: Thank you. You can consider the formats documented; google "jsch key file format" and this question is ranked fourth :)